# How to install the Dissenter Browser on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, repository, debian-installer

Is it in the repos?

I tried downloading the debian file from their website, but it gave me dependency issues
[image]

https://dissenter.com/#download

So what are the steps to getting this browser installed?

Comment: You already tried to install it with `sudo dpkg -i dissenter-browser-v0.66.99-amd64.deb` and then `sudo apt install -f`?

Comment: @PabloBianchi error on the first, can't find the launch binary on the latter.

Comment: The version of Dissenter included in this Snap is not the current version.

Comment: Why cant developers at Linux create a real free speech browser that does not make you "register" to speak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install the dissenter browser on Ubuntu, you need to have Snaps installed. Snaps are applications packaged with all their dependencies to run on all popular Linux distributions from a single build. They update automatically and roll back gracefully.

**Enable snapd**

If you’re running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) or later, including Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver), Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) and Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo), you don’t need to do anything. Snap is already installed and ready to go.

For versions of Ubuntu between 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) and 15.10 (Wily Werewolf), as well as Ubuntu flavours that don’t include snap by default, snap can be installed from the Ubuntu Software Centre by searching for `snapd`.

Alternatively, snapd can also be installed from the command line:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

You should either log out and back in again, or restart your system, to ensure snap’s paths are updated correctly.

**Install dissenter-browser**

To install dissenter-browser, simply use the following command:

```
sudo snap install dissenter-browser
```

**Resolving possible post-installation warnings**

After installation, upon launching you might get the following message:

```
You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --no-sandbox. Stability and security will suffer
```

To disable the message telling "that you're using an unsupported command-line flag --no-sandbox" you must enable user namespaces with sysctl:

```
sudo sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

To make it persist after reboot:

```
echo kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone = 1 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/00-local-userns.conf
```

Comment: Almost ready to accept this as an answer. Upon Launch, however it says, `You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --no-sandbox. Stability and security will suffer` << why is it saying this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Akiva, i've edited the answer to include the resolution of this problem. You could accept the answer if this resolves the issue

Comment: I am using ubuntu 21.04 and it does not work for me. Is here anything else that cam be done?